# EJB - How to search by non-indexed fields?

Tags: java, database, ejb

I'm trying to create "search engine" on my DB.

I have a table with Id, Name and Description.
When I have an Id I can get the record with this Id by find().
But if I want to get records by Name or Description how can I do that? Did I've to set the Name as index?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, if you have to frequently query a table by one of its fields and the table contains many records, it might be a good idea to create an index for that field in the database.

About the other question: if you need to get records by name, by description or by some other field and you're using JPA, then use the [JPQL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbtg.html) query language. For example, assuming that the entity is of type `MyEntity` (with fields `id`, `name`, `description`) the following query will return a list of entities with name `aName`:

```
EntityManager em = ...         // get the entity manager
Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT me FROM MyEntity me WHERE me.name = :name");
q.setParameter("name", aName); // aName is the name you're looking for
List<MyEntity> results = (List<MyEntity>) q.getResultList();
```

Read more about the Java Persistence API in the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbpz.html).